# Python: comparing two multi-fasta files of the same set of proteins with parser - to find and count mutations after treatment

Tags: python, parsing, statistics, bioinformatics, fasta

My task is to count the mutations  occured in several proteins after a treatment. The sequences are all present in the two files in the same order. I opened both files with the fasta parser (SeqIO.parse) in biopython and I got all the proteins listed (separated before and after the treatment).

My question:

- How can I zip the parsers together to count the mutations?

```html
from Bio import SeqIO
for normal_samples in SeqIO.parse("/data/statistic/normal_samples", "fasta"):
    print(normal_samples.id)
    print(repr(normal_samples.seq))
    print(len(normal_samples))
    
for treated_samples in SeqIO.parse("/data/statistic/with_treatment", "fasta"):
    print(normal_samples.id)
    print(repr(normal_samples.seq))
    print(len(normal_samples))
    
dict_n_t = dict(zip(normal_samples & treated_samples))
```

Comment: You could also put this question on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- That the sequences are in the same order in both files
- That only point mutations occur (so that the length of the corresponding sequences in the two files are identical)
- And that you are obly interested in the mutation count, not their locations

you can use the following code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

normal_samples = SeqIO.parse("/data/statistic/normal_samples", "fasta")
treated_samples = SeqIO.parse("/data/statistic/with_treatment", "fasta")


for normal, treated in zip(normal_samples, treated_samples):
    if normal.id == treated.id:
        mutations = sum(1 for n, t in zip(str(normal.seq), str(treated.seq)) if n != t)
        print(f"Found {mutations} mutation(s) for id {normal.id}")
```